# When determining the solution of a system of equations with free variables, can any set of variables be selected as the free variable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

[In this example](https://imgur.com/2KpF9Dg) $x_3$ and $x_4$ were the non-pivot variables and therefore used as the free variables. Is it possible to select any two variables as free variables and if not, is there a general rule/way to tell if the variables you want to use as the free variable can actually be used as free variables?

I attempted manipulate the solution so $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the free variables but it seems I cannot escape using at least one of $x_3$ or $x_4$ as the free variable as one equation has $x_3 - x_4$ and another has $x_4 - x_3$.

Comment: The answer to your title in general: No

Comment: Consider the system consisting of the single equation $x+0y=0$. Is $x$ free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to my comment, let us first look at your exercise. We can rewrite these 4 equations as $$-x_3+x_4=x_1-1$$
$$-x_3+x_4=1-x_2$$
$$x_3=x_3$$
$$x_4=x_4$$

Now let us assume that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are free. This means we can pick anything we want for them. Let's choose $x_1=4$ and $x_2=5$. This results in the system $-x_3+x_4=3$ with $-x_3+x_4=-4$ and this system has no solutions!. In order for your overall system to work, it turns out that $x_1$ and $x_2$ cannot be chosen arbitrarily, but for $x_3$ and $x_4$, it won't matter. Another example where you cannot arbitrarily choose your own choice of free variable is when one variable has been "assigned" a fixed value.
example:
$$x_1=4$$
$$x_2+x_3=5$$
$$0=0$$
You have a choice to pick $x_2$ or $x_3$ as your free variable, but $x_1$ is determined no matter what.

Comment: Can one of $x_1$ or $x_2$ be the free variable, just not both? If I add the first to the second equation I got $x_3-x_4+x_1 = 1$ and $x_1 + x_2 = 2$; it seems like I can express $x_3$ or $x_4$ and $x_1$ or $x_2$ as two of the remaining variables. In general how would you tell beforehand whether you can use a certain set of variable as free variables?

Comment: No, that is not going to work. If say $x_1$ is free, then it is still possible that get an inconsistent system for some $x_2$.

Comment: I get that in this example $x_1$ and $x_2$ cannot be both free, but can I use one of $x_1$ or $x_2$ with one of $x_3$ or $x_4$ as free variables? If I set say $x_1=x_1$ and $x_4=x_4$ as the free variables and write $x_2$ and $x_3$ in terms of $x_1$ and $x_4$, I would get $x_3 = 1-x_1+x_4$ and $x_2 = 2 - x_1$ (latter being the sum of the two equations), is this system also inconsistent?

Comment: Give it a try. Make a vector equation as the general solution with $x_1$ free.

Comment: From what I did above with $x_1$ and $x_4$ as free variables, I would get $[x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4] = [0, 2, 1, 0] + x_1[1, -1, -1, 0] + x_4[0, 0, 1, 1]$. I couldn't detect any inconsistencies with this equation and same if I were to take any combination other than $x_1$ and $x_2$ as free variables.

Comment: Looks like you found a possible way. Seems like we both learned something here. That said, I don't think may textbooks would go that route to establish free variables. But I admit, I can't detect inconsistencies either!